# Positive semidefinite matrix multiplied on both sides by a projector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P$ be a projection matrix and $A$ be a positive semidefinite matrix. Is it true that $P A P$ is positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\cdot, \cdot)$ denote the inner product and let $B$ be a self-adjoint matrix, then

$$(BABx, x)=(ABx, B^*x)=(A(Bx), Bx) \ge 0.$$